# fill in missing data with previous non-null value - but limited to simple SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a table of values, and need to fill in the blanks with the prior non-null values.

```
Store  SKU  YearNo  MonthNo  StockQty
001   010C   2018    6       34
001   010C   2018    7       NULL
001   010C   2018    8       NULL
001   010C   2018    9       46
002   010C   2018    6       15
002   010C   2018    7       14
002   010C   2018    8       NULL
002   010C   2018    9       NULL
```

In the example above, I want to fill in the nulls with the previous non-null value, so at store 001 for SKU 010C, month 7 should become 34, month 8 should be 34; at store 001 for SKU 010C, months 8 and 9 should become 14.

Okay, there are various posts on how to do this with fancy APPLYs and CTEs and with statements etc. But here's the fly in the ointment...

I have to do this using only the drag and drop ETL tool abilities. That means I can select fields, I can apply simple formulas (eg CASE when Stock is null then 0), and I can pick joins from the dropdown list (INNER, LEFT OUTER, RIGHT OUTER). I cannot hand write custom sub-selects, partition overs, withs, create temp tables, or anything more advanced than the first week of an SQL class. Think MS Access drag and drop query builder kind of thing.

How can I accomplish this?  Anyone?

Comment: Why are you not allowed to use any actual sql? That seems a strange requirement. If you can't use any kind of functions you are stuck. You would want to use LAG here but i bet you can't use that.

Comment: You could probably use a very hackish and slow triangular join here. Would get you the data but it wouldn't be that fast.

Comment: Side note, I'm also interested as to why you aren't allowed to use more advanced tsql as @SeanLange questioned... is this part of a class? If so, it's a bad example for day 1 of tsql.

Comment: It's because it's a GUI driven ETL application that generates TSQL based on what fields you have checkmarked on and what dropdowns you select for the kind of join.  Anything I hand coded would be overwritten as soon as I compiled the code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could just self-join to your table N number of times and use `coalesce` or `isnull` or `case`. They'd all get you what you want. You'd need to know how many continual `NULL` columns to account for all the possibilities.

```
declare @table table (store varchar(3), sku varchar(4), YearNo int, MonthNo int, StockQty int null)
insert into @table
values
('001','010C',2018,6,34),
('001','010C',2018,7,NULL),
('001','010C',2018,8,NULL),
('001','010C',2018,9,46),

('002','010C',2018,6,15),
('002','010C',2018,7,14),
('002','010C',2018,8,NULL),
('002','010C',2018,9,NULL)

select distinct
    t1.store
    ,t1.sku
    ,t1.YearNo
    ,t1.MonthNo
    ,coalesce(t1.StockQty,t2.StockQty,t3.StockQty)
from
    @table t1
    left join @table t2 on
            t2.store = t1.store 
        and t2.YearNo = t1.YearNo 
        and t2.MonthNo = t1.MonthNo -1 
    left join @table t3 on
            t3.store = t1.store 
        and t3.YearNo = t1.YearNo 
        and t3.MonthNo = t1.MonthNo - 2
```

Or, as an update statement...

```
update t1    
    set StockQty = coalesce(t1.StockQty,t2.StockQty,t3.StockQty)
from
    @table t1
    left join @table t2 on
            t2.store = t1.store 
        and t2.YearNo = t1.YearNo 
        and t2.MonthNo = t1.MonthNo -1 
    left join @table t3 on
            t3.store = t1.store 
        and t3.YearNo = t1.YearNo 
        and t3.MonthNo = t1.MonthNo - 2  

select * from @table
```

Comment: I had to use and IsNull and Coalesce with stepping back 1, then 2, then 3, then 4, etc. all the way up to 12 (12 months in a year).  But it worked.

Answer (score 0):

That code should work with gaps bigger than 2 months. 
However, it still does not handle switch of a year.

```
SELECT * INTO #Tbl2 FROM (VALUES
('001','010C',2018,6,34),('001','010C',2018,7,NULL),('001','010C',2018,8,NULL),('001','010C',2018,9,46),
('002','010C',2018,6,15),('002','010C',2018,7,14),('002','010C',2018,8,NULL),('002','010C',2018,9,NULL))
x (Store,SKU,YearNo,MonthNo,StockQty)

SELECT t.Store, t.SKU, t.YearNo, t.MonthNo
    , StockQty = ISNULL(t.StockQty,t3.StockQty)
FROM #Tbl2 as t
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT MonthNo = MAX(ti.MonthNo) 
    FROM #Tbl2 as ti
    WHERE t.Store = ti.Store and t.SKU = ti.SKU and t.YearNo = ti.YearNo
        and t.MonthNo > ti.MonthNo and ti.StockQty is not null
) as t2
LEFT JOIN #Tbl2 as t3 ON t2.MonthNo = t3.MonthNo 
    and t.Store = t3.Store and t.SKU = t3.SKU and t.YearNo = t3.YearNo
```